# How to create a link with content bound to other cell's content in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, links

As stated in the tittle I'm trying to make the content of a cell that links to an other cell have it's display text be based on the other cell's content. Before I was able to do it by right clicking the cell and adding a link using the button (which would generate something that looks like `=HYPERLINK("#rangeid=someId";SomeSheet!A85)` ).

But earlier this year it looks like Google sheets has been updated and this no longer works. Now I only figured out how to either have a link on a cell or have text equal to an other cell's text but never managed to figure out to have both at once on the same cell.

**Example :**

Cell `A1` has "Hello i'm a cell living in this world"

What I would like is having Cell `B1` linking to `A1` but also display "Hello i'm a cell living in this world" (exactly `A1`'s text)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thanks for the welcome even though i'm new to webapps stackexchange only. I've been part of the stack comminuty for quite some time now so I think I know how it works ^^

Comment: Sorry about that. Never checked your profile before. Just trying to keep [Unanswered questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) down.

Comment: Haha no worries :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> What I would like is having Cell B1 linking to A1 but also display "Hello i'm a cell living in this world" (exactly A1's text)
> How can I achieve this?

**Step 1**
Right-click on cell `A1` and choose `Get link to this cell`
You will get a link like: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXX/edit#gid=1189434210&range=A1`

**Step 2**

In cell `B1` place the following formula using this `#gid=1189434210&range=A1` part of the link

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=1189434210&range=A1",A1)
```

[image: How to hyperlink to a single cell in the same Google sheet]

To create hyperlinks for a range use the `ARRAYFORMULA` function as well.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A4="",,HYPERLINK("#gid=1189434210&range="&A1:A4,A1:A4)))
```

[image: How to create multiple hyperlinks to a range in the same Google sheet]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313)

Comment: So there's no way to have the first parameter value for HYPERLINK generated automatically since that update?

Comment: I am afraid not. :(

Comment: I just realised that using this method, unlike before the google sheets update mentionned in my question, if i ever insert or delete a line, the links will become broken and won't refer to where they were meant to send me... Any clue on how to avoid this problem?